# CakePHP multiple select values not selected

Tags: cakephp

My Multiple select is is being populated correctly, and being saved successfully, however, the selected value/s are not being selected when editing.

My Form ->

```
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
        ...
        'AnaestheticTechnique',
        ...
    ));
```

My HABTM relationship

```
class PatientCase extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'AnaestheticTechnique' =>
                array(
                    'className'              => 'AnaestheticTechnique',
                    'joinTable'              => 'anaesthetic_techniques_patient_cases',
                    'foreignKey'             => 'patient_case_id',
                    'associationForeignKey'  => 'anaesthetic_technique_id',
                    'unique'                 => true
                ),
    );
}
```

In My controller

```
    $anaestheticTechniques = $this->PatientCase->AnaestheticTechnique->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('anaestheticTechniques'));
```

The name of the select input is generated as

> data[AnaestheticTechnique][AnaestheticTechnique][]

However, $this is returning

> $this->data[AnaestheticTechnique][0][]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: It's a bug with current releases. Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14669852/1230763

Comment: There is a problem with the current cake php release (2.3) stackoverflow.com/a/14669852/1230763 explains how to fix Thank you ADmad